# undefined reference to `g_app_info_launch_default_for_uri_async'

Tags: linker-errors, gtk3

I am trying to install gtk+-3.22.0 from source code on Fedora 24. ./configure completes successfully, but I receive the following error upon running `make`:

```
  CCLD     gtk-query-immodules-3.0
./.libs/libgtk-3.so: undefined reference to `g_app_info_launch_default_for_uri_finish'
./.libs/libgtk-3.so: undefined reference to `g_app_info_launch_default_for_uri_async'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:2984: recipe for target 'gtk-query-immodules-3.0' failed
```

Answer (score 2):

Those functions are available in GLib 2.50 onwards. It is possible that you are linking against the system version of GLib which is probably 2.48, although it is unclear how `configure` would have completed successfully in that case.